# AttributeError when unpickling an object

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to pickle an instance of a class in one module, and unpickle it in another.

Here's where I pickle:

```
import cPickle

def pickleObject():
    object = Foo()
    savefile = open('path/to/file', 'w')
    cPickle.dump(object, savefile, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


class Foo(object):
    (...)
```

and here's where I try to unpickle:

```
savefile = open('path/to/file', 'r')
object = cPickle.load(savefile)
```

On that second line, I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Foo'`

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`class Foo` must be importable via the same path in the unpickling environment so that the pickled object can be reinstantiated.

I think your issue is that you define `Foo` in the module that you are executing as main (`__name__ == "__main__"`).  Pickle will serialize the path (not the class object/definition!!!) to `Foo` as being in the main module.  `Foo` is not an attribute of the main unpickle script.

In this example, you could redefine `class Foo` in the unpickling script and it should unpickle just fine.  But the intention is really to have a common library that is shared between the two scripts that will be available by the same path. Example: define `Foo` in foo.py

Simple Example:

**$PROJECT_DIR/foo.py**

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

**$PROJECT_DIR/picklefoo.py**

```
import cPickle
from foo import Foo

def pickleObject():
    obj = Foo()
    savefile = open('pickle.txt', 'w')
    cPickle.dump(obj, savefile, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


pickleObject()
```

**$PROJECT_DIR/unpicklefoo.py**

```
import cPickle

savefile = open('pickle.txt', 'r')
obj = cPickle.load(savefile)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Jeremy Brown had the right answer, here is a more concrete version of the same point:

```
import cPickle
import myFooDefiningModule
def pickleObject():
    object = myFooDefiningModule.Foo()
    savefile = open('path/to/file', 'w')
    cPickle.dump(object, savefile)
```

and:

```
import cPickle
import myFooDefiningModule
savefile = open('path/to/file', 'r')
object = cPickle.load(savefile)
```

such that `Foo` lives in the same namespace in each piece of code.