# How to decipher this cPickle error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I have a pickled file called `classifier.pkl` that I am trying to load into another module. However, I get an error I don't understand.

My code to pickle:

```
features = ['bob','ice','snowing'] #... shortened for exposition's sake
def extract_features(document):
      return  {'contains(%s)'% word: (word in set(document)) 
                 for word in all_together_word_list} 
training_set = classify.util.apply_features(extract_features,tweets[0])
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
cPcikle.dump(open('cocaine_classifier.pkl','wb'))
```

My code to unpickle:

```
features, extract_features, classifier = 
         cPickle.load(open('cocaine_classifier.pkl','rb'))
```

My error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extract_features'
```

A while ago I made the `.pkl` file by pickling three things:

- features : list
- extract_features : function
- classifier : instance of NLTK Naive Bayes Classifier

Puzzlingly, I get the same error with the following code:

```
x = cPickle.load(open('cocaine_classifier.pkl','rb'))
```

Why can't I retrieve three things? Even when I'm not trying to unpack the tuple?

**Update**

As NPE pointed out the path of the function to be unpickled must exactly match the function into which its being unpickled. I was debugging and Terminal and so `from mod import *` loads everything into the namespace whereas `import mod as m` does not.

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to pickle those objects?

Comment: `cocaine_classifier`? I am intrigued...

Comment: @NPE: It's for some epidemiology research- really: http://tox.sinaiem.org/ (under construction). (Not trying to advertise just stating the reason)

Comment: When you say that you've pickled a function (`extract_features`), what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I'm thinking a possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614379/attributeerror-when-unpickling-an-object

Comment: @JonClements I did define my function again in the target script. It's not that easy to recreate the pickled file, because I don't have easy access to the variable called features. Is there some way to only unpickle parts of an object? (I assume serialization means no.)

Comment: @Blender updated with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you pickle a function, only the (fully-qualified) name of the function is pickled, not the function itself. This means that you have to have the function definition in place when you're unpickling.

Did you by any chance mean to pickle the *result* of calling `extract_features`?

Comment: No, I need to call the function. The code is spaghetti code I'm detangling and I'd be just as happy to rewrite the function or import it from a utilities file. But, I have to deal with it because I need the other parts of the pickled file.

Comment: As long as there is an `extract_features` function available under the same fully-qualified name as was used during the pickling, you should be able to unpickle just fine.

Comment: @mac389: If you are unsure about what that fully-qualified name was, perhaps `pickletools.dis` might be able to help: http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/pickletools.html#pickletools.dis

Comment: I can imagine that the fully qualified name is different because the file hierarchy was changed. If I can't recreate that hierarchy because it is too different, is it just a loss?

Comment: @mac389: Just disassemble the pickled file using `pickletools.dis`. It'll tell you the fully-qualified name. If, for example, I pickle `math.cos` and then disassemble the pickle, I see `GLOBAL 'math cos'`. Once you've done this, all you'll have to do is make sure that a function with that name exists, and you should be able to unpickle.

Comment: forgive my ignorance. Disassembling it shows GLOBAL '__main__ extract_features'. How can I call my function that- there is a space in and the word __main__ in it?

Comment: Here, `__main__` is the name of the module, and refers to your script. Does the script that you run to load the pickle contain a function called `extract_features`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21031/discussion-between-mac389-and-npe)